# SQLiteConnection is not defined

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add SQL lite to a phone project. I am following the  Peter Huene project and SQLite-net-wp8 - https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net - But I keep getting the error SQLiteConnection not defined. (I did set references and Nuget packages.)

The part I skipped is the conditional compilation symbols change he mentions (add USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE) - My property page does not show a build tab - I have looked all over for the place to make that change but can't find it. Any thoughts?

Here is what my structure looks like (basically):

- -Windows8PhoneMainProject
- -SQLiteProject

SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs files are under SQLiteproject (not sure where I should place them - it seems to make no difference)

What am I missing? I find not Build tab or Conditional Compilation Symbols setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer - thought I would share it. It was because I was using VB instead of C# - had to add a C# project. (see below)

To use SQLite for wp8 with VB you are going to need 3 projects.  The c++ SQLiteProject, the windows phone 8 VB project, and a C# windows phone 8 class library.   Add the SQLite.cs and SqliteAsync.cs to the c# class library and add a reference to the c# dll in the VB project

Answered by MS forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/46ff757a-3951-45fc-a267-2a221cd45006/sqlite-and-vb-cannot-see-sqliteconnection?forum=wptools